# Cypress : Run same test on 2 different url (to avoid copy paste same code)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

I would like to know if there is a way to rerun the same tests twice (second time with different url) to avoid copy paste of the exact same code should look like something like this :

```
describe('...', () => {
   before(() => cy.visit('/))

   describe('Series of tests ...', () => {
      // Tests goes here
   })

   after(() => {
     cy.visit('other url')
     cy.rerun() // Re run the describe right above with the new url is there a way to do something like this ?
   })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Cypress Lodash](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/_) to iterate a certain number of times.

```js
const urls = ['url1', 'url2'];

describe('...', () => {
  Cypress._.times(urls.length, ((index) => {
    it('Runs the test', () => {
      cy.visit(url[index]);
      // rest of test
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to iterate the urls directly,

```js
const urls = ['url1', 'url2'];

describe('...', () => {

  urls.forEach(url => {

    it('Runs the test', () => {
      cy.visit(url);
      // rest of test
    });
  });
});
```